# Not able to invoke a URL with credentials

Tags: ios

This is the URL I am trying to invoke:

```
https://myapp.something.com/IAMSMART.TFS/tfsdefects?username=austinSan\mcs234&password=Houston456
```

In my code I invoke it like this:

```
 NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

    [[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://myapp.something.com/IAMSMART.TFS/tfsdefects?username=austinSan\\mcs234&password=Houston456"] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];



    }]resume];
```

For some reason I always get the jsonObject as nil. The only difference between the original URL and my URL is the extra "\" added due to escape characters.

Comment: Do you need the extra escape character? I can't recollect having to put them in my urls.

Comment: If I don't put it then Xcode complains and also I get back a different message from server, failed to authenticate.

Comment: If your web server responds with 401 Authentication Required you can pass credentials by the `-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection  *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge` delegate - Maybe a little more secure.

Comment: This is just a demo so I want to keep it really simple!

Comment: Hi @johndoe -- Can you share more information?  Try this command NSLog(@"%@, %@, %@",data,response,error); -- So we can see what the whole response is.  There are a number of reasons why it could be possible to get nil from you JSON parsing (including no data, failed parse, authentication failure, etc) and logging the full result will help :)

Comment: You really need to log the error: anything before that is just guessing. Speaking of guessing, do you have a valid SSL cert signed by a valid certificate authority on the server? Does the host name on the cert match the host name of the URL? Is the cert expired? Can you try http: instead of https: to avoid cert problems?

Answer (score 0):

You need to percent escape your GET parameters

```
austinSan\mcs234
```

should actually be

```
austinSan%5Cmcs234
```

AFNetworking does this with the following method ([line 66](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.m)):

```
static NSString * AFPercentEscapedQueryStringKeyFromStringWithEncoding(NSString *string, NSStringEncoding encoding) {
    static NSString * const kAFCharactersToLeaveUnescapedInQueryStringPairKey = @"[].";

    return (__bridge_transfer  NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)string, (__bridge CFStringRef)kAFCharactersToLeaveUnescapedInQueryStringPairKey, (__bridge CFStringRef)kAFCharactersToBeEscapedInQueryString, CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding));
}
```

It is done by using the [`CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Reference/CFURLRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes) function